# Inverse of a $4 \times 4$ triangular block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to find the form of the inverse matrix of this $4 \times 4$ triangular block matrix (if it exists):
$$M=
\begin{bmatrix}
    A&?&?&?\\
    0&B&0&?\\
    0&0&C&?\\
    0&0&0&D\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Where $A, B, C, D$ are square matrices and with $'?'$ I've indicated some other entries of the square matrix which are unknown. Thanks for your help.

Comment: it would maybe help if you gave name to the unknown square matrices.

Comment: If '?' elements are *unknown* then you cannot calculate the inverse as the inverse are going to depend on those, thus, be unknown as well. What do you mean by "unknown"? A variable or an uncertainty?

Answer (score 0):

1. First invert D, then use it to by row operations solve ? in same column to 0.
2. Invert C, use it to solve away ? at top row.
3. Invert B, use it to solve away ? at top row.
4. Invert A

Done